# Average of all values and separate groups

Tags: sql, postgresql, metabase

How could I calculate an average of a column for all values and for each group specifically? 
Imagine, I have:

```
+-----+-----+
| val | grp |
+-----+-----+
|  1  |  A  |
+-----+-----+
|  3  |  A  |
+-----+-----+
|  2  |  B  |
+-----+-----+
|  2  |  B  |
+-----+-----+
|  5  |  C  |
+-----+-----+
|  1  |  C  |
+-----+-----+
```

What I want for the result is:

```
+-------+-----+
|  val  | grp |
+-------+-----+
| 2.333 | all |
+-------+-----+
|   2   |  A  |
+-------+-----+
|   2   |  B  |
+-------+-----+
|   3   |  C  |
+-------+-----+
```

Here we have a mean of each group and a mean of all groups combined.

Is there any nice way of doing this? I know it is inadvisable to do it like this, but as I am using Metabase I need to have it in this form for me to be able to do a comparison of group averages vs total average.

Any other solution or suggestion is also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres, you can use `grouping sets`:

```
select grp, avg(val)
from t
group by grouping sets ( (grp), () );
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `union`

```
  Select avg(value), 'all' from table
  Union 
  Select avg(value), grp from table 
  Group by grp
```